# What are the paṭiccasamuppāda theory and it's products?

Tags: theravada, philosophy, mahayana, terminology, pratityasamutpada

Is there any differences in Paṭiccasamuppāda ,Dependent arising and dependent co-arising?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dhamma Greetings Gawesaka, the answer is: No. The first word is Pāḷi and second and third are just [different English renditions](http://dsalsrv02.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.2:1:1091.pali.490951) of that expression. Best Wishes

Comment: Dhamma Greetings Mirco,  this is my first question. i wont to know the state of this community about Paṭiccasamuppāda.  Thanks for answering.